# jQuery Mobile: Page redirecting to Previous Page after a few seconds of opening the new page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

When I click on any link on a web page before the page is completely loaded, the new page shows up but after a few seconds I am redirected to the previous page. I think this is because the first page keeps loading in the background and when it is completely loaded JQM redirects back to that page.

Is there any way to prevent this ?

I am using : jQuery Mobile 1.4.4, jQuery v1.11.1, jQuery Migrate v1.2.1 and multi page wordpress website.

HTML :

```
<p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/A9ZMkhvjssA?autoplay=1" width="1024" height="700" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>
<div style="text-align:right;"><a id="skipContent" title="Home Page" href="http://192.168.1.62:8079/" style="color:#fff; font-weight:bold;">Skip Video &gt;&gt;</a></div>
```

JS

```
No JS Required for this as jQuery mobile automaically adds ajax based page navigation to links
```

Comment: Add more details, html markup, js code, jquery and jquery mobile versions, single or multi-page, etc.

Comment: I am using : jQuery Mobile 1.4.4, jQuery v1.11.1, jQuery Migrate v1.2.1, multi page wordpress website.